# escaping "\=" when using string_concatenate in SWIPL swi-prolog

Tags: escaping, prolog, swi-prolog, string-concatenation

i would like to escape the backslash in swipl when using string_concat.

Scenario 1-

```
string_concat('stack', ' overflow', Result).
Result = "stack overflow"
```

Scenario 2-

```
string_concat('stack', ' \=overflow', Result).
Syntax error: Undefined character escape in quoted atom or string: `\='
```

Scenario 3-

```
string_concat('stack', ' \\=overflow', Result).
Result = "stack \\=overflow"
```

Now, scenario1 behaves as expected. I am faced with a situation explained in scenario2, where in i need to concatenate a string that contains a backslash and equalto. ie, string1 has just text, string2 has text with \= also inside it, and my result should be string1 and string2 concatenated. However, using just \= as in scenario2 results in an error asking me to escape the sequence. Now, escaping as in scenario3 gives me two backslashes and the equal sign. I do not want two backslashes.

My output should be exactly `stack \=overflow`. Is there some escape sequence or method that I am missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double backslash are there just for display:

```
?- string_concat(stack, ' \\=overflow', X), writeln(X).
stack \=overflow
X = "stack \\=overflow".
```

but you can change the behaviour using this flag:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(character_escapes,false).
true.

?- writeln('stack \=overflow').
stack \=overflow
true.
```

with default value `true` I get the error you report:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(character_escapes,true).
true.

?- writeln('stack \=overflow').
ERROR: Syntax error: Undefined character escape in quoted atom or string: `\='
ERROR: writeln('stack \
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: =overflow') .
```

Anyway, I think you should reset its value to default when done, or double check your SW for unwanted side effects on literals.

HTH

Comment: thanks for the flag help. however, i see that when using string_concat, I still get the 2 backslashes. See code:

 set_prolog_flag(character_escapes, false), string_concat('stack', '\=overflow', X), writeln(X).

Gives output as:
stack\=overflow
X = "stack\\=overflow"

Since I need to use X in other places in the program, it shouldn;t have the \\=, instead it should only have \=. Any suggestion on this? Thanks.